# Rotating a page 180 degrees along its edge

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I was trying to accomplish this with:

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, XYZ);  
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix,degToRad(90),[1,0,0]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix,-pageTurn,[0,1,0]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix,degToRad(-90),[1,0,0]);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, inverseXYZ);
```

The first moves to the top left point it was drawn, the second rotates perpendicular to X and the third actually does the rotating.  It rotates kind of correctly, but it's like it's orbiting the center of the "book" instead of keeping steady on its edge.  `pageTurn` is an angle in radians updated by an animation.  I think it could be my use of `inverseXYZ`.  I can't find the method on mat4 that does inverse.  (I know it's inverse, but can't find documentation on it)

I was thinking it could be the perspective matrix as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate an object around a point p (in this case, a page along a point on its edge) by first translating the matrix by -p, then doing the rotation, and finally translating the matrix by p. Visually, you move the object so that the point of rotation is at the origin, then you rotate the object, and finally put it back to where it was.

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, vec3.negate(edgePoint, tmpVec));
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, turnAngle, [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, edgePoint);
```